# Time condition not working in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I try to display a message, if it is 11 oclock.
This is what I've tried:

```
temp.contentHome.20 {
  wrap = <div class="clearfix heading_wrapper">|</div>
  10.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 image-left">|</div>
  20.wrap = <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-7 text-center">|</div>

  30 = TEXT
  30.value = <p>default</p>
  30.stdWrap.wrap = <div style="margin-top: 1em" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-right">|</div>
}

[hour = 11]
    temp.contentHome.20.30.value = <p>Success! It is 11 o'clock</p>
[ELSE]
    temp.contentHome.20.30.value = <p>It is not 11 o'clock!</p>
[END]
```

However, the output is always `It is not 11 o'clock!`, even though it is 11 oclock like `date` proves.

[image: server time]

Why is the condition not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first look it seems to be correct.

Try to add the current time to the COA:

```
temp.contentHome.20.40 = TEXT
temp.contentHome.20.40 {
  data = date:U
  strftime = %H:%M
}
```

Maybe your server time doesn't match your localtime. Please Check the timezone settings in the install tool (`[SYS][phpTimeZone]`).

Also it is possible that the caching is not refreshed so the condition is not checked.

To the end: Have you an COA or COA_INT on temp.contentHome.20?

Comment: It was indeed because the wrong timezone was set in the installation tool in the typo3 backend. After I've set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['phpTimeZone']` to `Europe/Berlin`, it works :)